# append tables dynamically

Tags: excel, powerquery, tablename

Is there a way to create/append a dataset dynamically with all tables in an excel file with powerquery ? I guess I need a function to append all the tables in the below list.

all tables have the same column names.

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Kind] = "Table")),
Name = #"Filtered Rows"[Name]
```

table names as example

```
Table1
Table12
Table143
Table14354
```

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of doing it in the current file you could use the following, and on the assumption that all the tables have the same column names you could try the following

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
    Custom1 = Table.SelectRows(Source, each try List.Contains(Table.ColumnNames(_[Content]),"Col1") otherwise false)
in
    Custom1
```

in this example I've got a bunch of tables, all with the same headers, a print range and filtered range in the file

The Source step, ie `Excel.CurrentWorkbook()`, brings in the following
[image]

The 2nd step checks the `[Content]` column to see if the column names includes Col1 (obviously you'd need to change this for a header value from your tables), with some error handling built in.
[image]

Comment: previously i solved this with ``#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(xfile, each (try Table.RowCount([Content])>0 otherwise false)),`` but thanks for your time& effort anyways...

Comment: No worries, however a potential flaw with using Table.RowCount() is that it will pick up any data that returns a table in the Content column, which isn’t just Excel Tables - it includes Print Areas and Named Ranges. So you could end up with duplicate or unneeded data that you then have to deal with later on in your PQ

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer... after filtering the Tables, we need to combine them..

though i still couldnt manage it in the same file...

```
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\777\filename.xlsx"), null, true),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Kind] = "Table")),
CombineTable= Table.Combine(#"Filtered Rows"[Data])
```

Comment: If you want to do it in the file containing the tables start a new blank query with Excel.CurrentWorkbook() as your source. Then you can do the same filtering/combination steps

Comment: thank you for the comment. i cannot filter tables in the Content...  is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean you “cannot filter tables in the Content”? It should be obvious what you need to do, maybe add some screenshots

Comment: after using ``Excel.CurrentWorkbook()`` i need to filter only Tables in the content. as it is a data type, not text, powerquery does not allow me to filter.

Comment: @Ben  i have error tables in the ``Excel.CurrentWorkbook()`` but it has only ``Content`` and ``Name`` , it doesnt have any ``Kind`` option so i can filter those...